# Angular How to test "new Subject<void>() "

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm new to Angular unit testing. I have used `new Subject<void>()` in my service , but I am unable to write jasmine code for it.

**service.ts file**

```js
public _refreshNeeded = new Subject<void>();

get refreshNeeded() {
  console.log(this._refreshNeeded)
  return this._refreshNeeded;
}

getDetails() {
  return  this.httpClient.get<Data[]>(`${this.API_URL}`);
}

postDetails(user: Data, seqcode: any): Observable<Data[]>{
  return this.httpClient.post<Data[]>(`${this.API_URL}`, user).pipe(tap(()=> {
      this._refreshNeeded.next()
  }));
}
```

**component.ts file**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.corpTrustService._refreshNeeded.subscribe(() => {
    this.getDetails();
  });

  this.getDetails();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet of what you have tried so far, for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Comment: Can you provide details on what you were trying to test but were unable to figure out?

Comment: I'm trying to test refreshNeeded on ngOnInit

Comment: @Sonam: Welcome to SO, I have written an article to help beginners in Unit Testing of angular. Check out :https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49 . You should create a `stub` service and insert it in `TestBed`  using `useClass`. Take a look at it and update your question with your findings :)

Comment: any update on this issue?